# How do I determine if a path is relative or absolute with VB Scripting Host

Tags: winapi, vbscript

How do I determine if a path is relative or absolute in Visual Basic Script.

In VBA, I'd call the Win32 Api function PathIsRelative

```
Private Declare Function PathIsRelative Lib "shlwapi" _
    Alias "PathIsRelativeA" _
   (ByVal pszPath As String) As Long
```

However, it's not possible to call into a DLL from VBS, so I cannot use
the Win32 Api.

René

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late, but according to Microsoft *[Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths)* page referenced by a Helen's comment, a path is absolute if:

> - a UNC name of any format, which always start
>   with two backslash characters ("`\\`").
> - A disk designator with a backslash, for example "`C:\`" or "`d:\`".
> - A single backslash, for example, "`\directory`" or "`\file.txt`".

*Otherwise*, according to the page, the path is relative.

At most the first three characters are to be checked here (checking if the path is valid, i.e. whose items don't contain illegal characters or aren't a reserved name like `CON`) seems out of the scope.

Here's my two cents:

```
Function isAbsolutePath(path)
    isAbsolutePath = True
    Dim first : first = UCase(Left(path, 1))
    Dim secondNthird : secondNthird = UCase(Mid(path, 2, 2))
    If first > "A" and first < "Z" and secondNthird = ":\" Then Exit Function
    If first = "\" Then Exit Function
    isAbsolutePath = False
End Function
```

Test code:

```
Function IIf(clause, thenValue, elseValue)
    If CBool(clause) Then
        IIf = thenValue
    Else 
        IIf = elseValue
    End If
End Function

For Each path in Array ( _
        "C:\Test1", _
        "D:\Test2\", _
        "3:\Test4", _
        "CD:\Test5", _
        "\\Test6\", _
        "\Test7", _
        "Test8", _
        ".\Test9\", _
        "..\Test10" _
    )
    Response.Write path & ": " & IIf(isAbsolutePath(path), "absolute", "relative")  & "</br>"
Next
```

Output:

```
C:\Test1: absolute
D:\Test2\: absolute
3:\Test4: relative
CD:\Test5: relative
\\Test6\: absolute
\Test7: absolute
Test8: relative
.\Test9\: relative
..\Test10: relative
```

Of course, as said, you must ensure next your path is valid (`3:\Test4` is relative but illegal).

Answer (score 3):

```
set oFSO = CREATEOBJECT("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

relativePath = ""
absolutePath = "c:\test"

MsgBox UCase(relativePath) = UCase(oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(relativePath))
MsgBox UCase(absolutePath) = UCase(oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(absolutePath))
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is an answer to the question?

Answer (score -1):

```
dim position
position = InStr("your-path", ":")

If position > 0 Then
  ''# absolute path
else
  ''# relative path
end if
```

Comment: I should point out that the ; and // are both java/c/c++/etc like.

Comment: Checking for a presence of a colon isn't enough. For example, `C:\file.txt` is a full path whereas `C:file.txt` is relative (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths).

Comment: @Helen: great info, thanks but can't figure out where this path relates to?

Comment: `C:file.txt` refers to the `file.txt` file in the current folder on drive `C`. Similarly, `C:folder\file.txt` refers to a file in the `folder` subfolder of the current folder; `C:..\file.txt` -- to a file in the parent folder of the current folder, and so on.

Comment: `\\some\share\file.txt` is another absolute path which does not contain a `:`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it would look better this way:

```
FUNCTION IsPathAbsolute( testedPath)

set oFSO = CREATEOBJECT("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

IsPathAbsolute = UCASE( testedPath) = UCASE( oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName( testedPath))
```

Comment: Won't work reliably, since GetAbsolutePathName also normalizes the path, e.g. `C:\foo\..\bar`will be normalized to `C:\bar`